# Redirect all subfolders from domain A to same subfolder in domain B

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, prestashop, http-status-code-301

I have 2 domains, and need to redirect all subfolders from domain A to the same subfolder in domain B.

Domain A = Wordpress
Domain B = Prestashop 1.7

Example of what I need to accomplish:

`https://domainA.com/subfolder1` -> 301 -> `https://domainB.com/subfolder1`

There's a lot of subfolders in domain A, so I need my rule to be general

Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why the emphasis on "subfolders"? Not _all_ content? So what with resources on top level?

Comment: What constitutes a "subfolder"? A physical subdirectory in the root of domainA? Or simply URLs that contain at least one path segment? What about "files" (or URLs?) within those "subfolders"? Should "files" also be redirected? Or do you literally only want to redirect requests to the subdirectory itself (as your question appears to suggest)?

Comment: Also, does domainA and domainB point to different filesystems?

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite , yes it points to two different filesystems. Thanks for your support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand the question such that you actually want to redirect all content from one to another domain. That could be done like that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainA\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://domainB.com%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301,END]
```

It makes sense to start out with a `R=302` temporary redirection and only change that to a `R=301` permanent redirection once you have sorted out everything to your satisfaction. That prevents caching issues.

Such rule can be implemented in a distributed configuration file (".htaccess") if their consideration is enabled for the host "domainA.com". You should prefer to use the real http server's host configuration instead though, if you have access to that.

---

UPDATE:
In your comment you confirm that you indeed only want to redirect "subfolders", not all resources. I understand "subfolders" as URLs with a path component that has a "subfolder" followed by a "/" and some other resource after that. Though that does not have to correspond to actual folders in the server side file system at all...

In that case this variant should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainA\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?[^/]+/ https://domainB.com%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301,END]
```

Obviously the same hints as above apply...

Comment: Thanks. Not quite that. I want to redirect only subfolders, all the subfolders to their match in Domain B

Comment: Thats just perfect! Thanks again, im not familiar with Regex ( yet ;) )

Comment: OReilly has a number of books about regular expressions if you did not catch them in compexity theory. I'd recommend that one: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mastering-regular-expressions/0596528124/

Comment: Thanks. Yes, im planning on improving my skills in regex.

Answer (score 2):

You have to edit htaccess file of wordpress domain website.

Add htaccesss code like below.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/subfolder1/(.*)$ https://domainB.com/subfolder1/$1
```

It will be redirect https://domainA.com/subfolder1 to https://domainB.com/subfolder1

You must have to try. I hope this can be helpful. thanks

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that works, but my question is: i need a general rule that redirects all that is a subfolder from Domain A to same subfolder in Domain B.

Comment: Thanks again. If i understand correctly, with that rule i'd need to explicitly add every subfolder with that pattern. Is there any general rule that points all subfolders from domain A to point to same subfolder in domain B? I mean... All of them without adding a rule for each one of them. Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative solution....

> it points to two different filesystems.

In that case, you don't need the additional *condition* that checks the requested hostname. (Unless you are hosting *other* domains on this account?)

In order to detect whether the requested URL-path contains an initial subfolder you could just check to see whether the URL-path contains a slash (`/`), rather than explicitly matching the first path segment, since this isn't used in the *substitution* string.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule / https://domainB.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

In `.htaccess` (*directory* context) the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash, so if a slash occurs anywhere in the URL-path we can assume that there must be a "subfolder". Or, there is *path-info*, but since this is a WordPress site (and I assume you are using "pretty permalinks", otherwise the existing answer won't work either) then you don't have path-info on any legitimate URLs.

This redirect needs to go near the top of the `.htaccess` file, *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` section.